# Using ThreadPool to connect to multiple TCP servers simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, networking, tcp

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
<MTAThread()>
Sub Main()
    Dim maxthreads As Integer = 10
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maxthreads, maxthreads)
    Dim serverlist() As String = File.ReadAllLines("final.txt")

    Dim servernum As New CountdownEvent(serverlist.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
    For Each a In serverlist
        Dim args(1) As Object
        args(0) = a
        args(1) = servernum
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf ping), args)
    Next
    servernum.Wait()


    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Sub ping(ByVal server() As Object)

    Dim serverinfo() As String = Split(server(0), ",")
    Dim socketclient As New TcpClient
    Console.WriteLine(serverinfo(0))

    Try
        socketclient.Connect(serverinfo(0), serverinfo(1))
    Catch ex As Exception
        If socketclient.Connected = False Then
            Throw New Exception("Server Offline")
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Unknown Error Occured")
        End If
    End Try

       Dim stream As NetworkStream = socketclient.GetStream
        stream.ReadTimeout = 1000
        stream.WriteTimeout = 1000
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = {&HFE}
        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
        Dim bytes(421) As Byte
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(421))
        socketclient.Close()
        Dim trimbytes(bytes.Length - 3) As Byte
        Array.Copy(bytes, 3, trimbytes, 0, bytes.Length - 3)
        Dim returndata As String = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(trimbytes)

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 1 To 241 Step 2
            If trimbytes(i) <> 0 Then
                sb.Append(ChrW(BitConverter.ToInt16(trimbytes, i)))
            End If
        Next i
        Dim message() As String = sb.ToString.Split("§")

        'Write processed server information to the console
        Console.WriteLine("Received -->" & message(1) & " " & message(2) & " | " & serverinfo(0))

        server(1).signal()



End Sub
End Module
```

Above is my code, what I basically want to do is to get two (or more) ips from the text file, connect to both of them via TCP on two different threads and get the responses from the servers.

Now, the problem here is that; for whatever reason one of the two servers get a response but the other doesn't. I've made sure both of the servers are online and accepting connections. I've also tried having the same server on both lines of the text file so that the same ip is being used on both threads but this doesn't work either. Even when the two ips are the same, one gets a response but not the other; which must mean I'm doing something horribly wrong.

When I use one server rather than 1+ everything works perfectly and I get the response I'm looking for, anything more than 1 and it looks like the first thread that runs produces the response but not anything that runs later. Any help will be appreciated.

I have also tried using Paarallel.For but ended up running into the same issue.

```
Parallel.ForEach(serverlist, _
             Sub(currentElement)
                 ping(currentElement)
             End Sub)
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out parts of the ping function? Does multithreading work if you remove the network access completely? If you only remove the `stream.Write` call?

Comment: @didierc  it's not very clear what you're asking but multithreading works perfectly when I've got some other code in place of the pinging procedures. If I were to remove network access, the tcpclient would fail to connect to the server which would throw an exception, and if I were to comment out `stream.Write` I wouldn't get the response I'm looking for as the server requires that I send `&HFE` before it sends back a response